# Refresh Spring Redis Cache Manager Bean at run time using Spring Boot Actuator refresh endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am using **Spring boot 1.5.15** in my app. I have added cache support with **Redis** as Cache server and have used Spring Caching annotations to handle the cache operations.

With Spring Caching and Redis , there was no way to provide separate expiration times for each of the caches I use.

So, I have customized CacheManager bean as below and created a configuration class to get the expiration values in yaml file for  individual caches I use.

```
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
                RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);

                cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
                List<CacheConfig> cacheConfigList = appConfig.getCacheConfig();
                    if (null != cacheConfigList && cacheConfigList.size() > 0) {
                    cacheManager.setExpires(getCacheExpirySecondsMap(cacheConfigList));
                }
                return cacheManager;
            }

   public Map<String, Long> getCacheExpirySecondsMap(List<CacheConfig> cacheConfigList) {
        Map<String, Long> cacheConfigMap = cacheConfigList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getName(), x -> x.getExpirySeconds()));
        return cacheConfigMap;
    }
```

My CacheConfig bean has below fields,

```
String name;
Long expirySeconds;
```

My AppConfig has below fields,

```
List<CacheConfig> cacheConfig;
```

Through yaml I get the values as below,

```
app:
  defaultCacheExpiryTime: 10
  cache-config:
  - name: members                 
    expiry-seconds: 60            
  - name: users
    expiry-seconds: 70
  - name: plans
    expiry-seconds: 85
```

This works fine. But, now I have a requirement to dynamically change the expiry values of the caches at runtime without cycling the service.

I tried adding **@RefreshScope** to the Cache Manager bean and also externalizing the configuration in a Config Repo and served by Spring Cloud Config Server. But, when I invoke **actuator /refresh** endpoint I do not see the **CacheManager** bean refreshed. But, I do see the CacheConfig bean updated with the values. Also, I see the response to /refresh includes the updated fields for which expiry values have been changed.

Basically, I want to update the **RedisCacheManager** Bean with the new Expiration times so that they will be applied for all existing as well as new cache keys of different caches. Also, I am using **Spring Cloud Edgware.SR4**.

I have shared the code I used in the repo ,including the config server, config repo and the cache-service in the repository, https://github.com/quickfox123/cachedemos

If anyone knows how to resolve the issue please help me.